# como fazer um ranking em php?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

[Ajuda] ranking em arquivo.php

imagem ilustrativa: http://prntscr.com/kl11df

imagem do site(pág principal): http://prntscr.com/kl12b3

imagem das contas criadas para teste: http://prntscr.com/kl13gz

utilizo o Xamp, para mostrar as contas criadas eu vou ter que entrar  no localhost/phpmyadmin.
Bom pessoal eu fiz um designar para o ranking dos cincos melhores, quero que apareça esse ranking na página principal do Site. Utilizando sql para armazenamento de dados das contar dos jogadores, esse ranking é para mostrar os top rank em level.
Agradeço desde já

Comment: O gesior acc já tem essa função de listar os rankings, qual versão você está usando?

Comment: creio que 8.54 Bom eu sou novo na área de website, só sei fazer remake de algumas coisas, há alguma rede social ou algum lugar onde posso tirar a minha duvida em chat?

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é você deixar claro qual plataforma está usando, pois quem não joga esse jogo não vai saber do que se relaciona.

## Gesior ACC

Versões recentes do Gesior Acc têm essa barra lateral indicando o ranking, não é necessário refazer a `query`, basta mudar direto no arquivo do ranking.

Caso sua versão não tenha por padrão essa feature, você vai precisar que um método em alguma classe existente para listar os 5 top's.

query

```
SELECT name, level FROM accounts ORDER BY level ASC LIMIT 5
```

## Exemplos

Caso você não saiba como funciona a estrutura do projeto, basta dar uma olhada no GitHub (não oficial, se é que existe um oficial).

Nessa versão (comunitária) na pasta `/pages/` no arquivo `highscores.php` tem tudo que você precisa.

trecho da informação

```
$skills = new Highscores($id, 100, $page, $world_id, $vocation);
```

Comment: "deixar claro qual plataforma está usando" ... Tipo eu... Que não sabia e votei para fechar. XD

Comment: Tipo, a plataforma é de um jogo rpg Online, estou com dificuldade em posicionar a tabela do ranking ná página principal do site e  de fazer a script para que funcione tudo corretamente